# summing selected values of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagrid

I using this code for sum selected cells. Its work good but when user selecte cell where is letter is throws exceptions : ) how can i secure when in selectet cells is letters dont make sum

i asked same question but there i cannot add my code

```
 private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cLoadName"]))
            {
                float nextNumber = 0;
                float sumNumbers = 0;

                                        nextNumber = float.Parse(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].FormattedValue.ToString());
                    sumNumbers += nextNumber;


                tsslSumSelected.Text = "ჯამი: " + sumNumbers;
                tsslTotalSelected.Text = "მონიშნული: " + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }    

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cLoadName"]))
            {
                float nextNumber = 0;
                float sumNumbers = 0;

                    if (float.TryParse(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].FormattedValue.ToString(), out nextNumber))
                        sumNumbers += nextNumber;


                tsslSumSelected.Text = "ჯამი: " + sumNumbers;
                tsslTotalSelected.Text = "მონიშნული: " + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }    

    }
```

Comment: it does not work for me. Can u simply give code which sum sum only numbers if selected cell contains letters dont sum

Comment: That is what the code is supposed to do. I checks to see if the cell contains valid number. Why is it not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ComputeGridTot()
{
    try
    {
        decimal qty= 0;
        decimal price = 0;
        decimal tax = 0;
        decimal Total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < drGrdView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (drGrdView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString() == blcnt.ToString())
            {
                qty += Convert.ToDecimal(drGrdView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                price += Convert.ToDecimal(drGrdView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                tax += Convert.ToDecimal(drGrdView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                Total += Convert.ToDecimal(drGrdView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);

             }
        }
        lblGTax.Text = tax.ToString();
        lblGQty.Text = qty.ToString();
        lblGPrice.Text = price.ToString();
        lblGTot.Text = Total.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sumcolumns()
        {
            int Sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < DGV30.SelectedRows.Count; ++i)
            {
                Sum += Convert.ToInt32(DGV30.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                textBox7.Text = Sum.ToString();
                decimal text1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox7.Text);
                textBox7.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###0}", text1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**